# Database design involving a foreign key pointing to different tables

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, rdbms

Suppose that we have a "Cash Transactions" table, as its name implies it keeps the track of cash I/O. There might be a case in the future where we are having cash transactions about completely different concepts. Since we model these "concepts" in the database, we would like to have some form of identifiability between transactions and the concepts. In other words, I would like to know from which table and which entry a money transaction comes from.

I've come up with two solutions; first one involving a meta-data column identifying the table and a foreign key, second one with foreign keys as many as it needs and only using the non-null one so we know by the merit of the column name which table to look for it.

I reckon they both will work but they feel hacky. It feels like there is an elegant solution but its not these two. Or perhaps I hit the limit of relational DB design and I should resolve to NoSQL? How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a link table, the cash transactions should be unaware of what table to link to.